# connect and fetch remote MySQL server from Mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I ma following [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) on how to connect to a remote MySQL server, however It seems the command doesn't work and often results in `Operation timed out` when trying to connect to the server:

```
 ssh mysql.xxxxx.com
```

I can connect directly from my hosting account but not through the Shell on my Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a firewall or other network security device in place that prevents you from being able to connect from your Mac.  Also, it is possible that the MySQL server is not configured to allow inbound network connections.

You might ask your hosting provider if they filter access to the MySQL port (default is 3306), or if your host is pre-configured with a firewall, and you might check your MySQL configuration file to ensure it is listening for inbound connections.

Answer (score 0):

When you ssh into a remote server, and you do not specify a user name, ssh defaults to your current user.

```
bobs-macbook-pro:~ bob$ ssh server.acme.com
```

is the same as:

```
bobs-macbook-pro:~ bob$ ssh bob@server.acme.com
```

Try using your username when 'sshing' into the remote mysql machine.

There are two ways to specify your username, either one should work.

```
1. bobs-macbook-pro:~ bob$ ssh bob@server.acme.com
2. bobs-macbook-pro:~ bob$ ssh server.acme.com -l bob
```